# Visual Studio CssLint Css Grid validation fails

Tags: css, visual-studio-2017, css-grid, csslint

I am using the new Css Grid layout, but it seems that the CssLint version used by Visual Studio 2017 does not support that.
I get the validation error seen in the screenshot:

[image: CssLint validation error]

Does anyone know how to get it updated, or need i just wait for it?

Comment: A validation error in Visual Studio doesn't mean the rule won't work in the browser. Besides CSS Validators are unreliable, since the standard for validation is generally higher than the standard for browser implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41406627/3597276

Comment: I know that validators are not all that reliable, but i am asking if anyone knows of a solution from the Visual Studio team to support CSS Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now supported by the Visual Studio 2017