# -ms-flex-positive is not a known CSS property

Tags: css

I have added new content in my project and new CSS file has some validation errors.

How to resolve this issue

Comment: That's an old IE10 syntax which is why it's probably something you can ignore. - https://github.com/stylus/nib/pull/299

Comment: If you validate invalid, vendor-prefixed property names, what are you expecting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a warning which you can ignore.

Someone has asked this before here: [Not recognized by CSS Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406627/css-pointer-events-and-appearance-properties-not-recognized-by-css-validator)

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful.